# how can i match Two different pattern csv files using pattern matching in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

i am having two csv files.one file contains the order like date,source,destination,amount. second csv file having the order  like source,date,amount,destination so how can i do pattern matching using spring batch?

here is my code to map one csv.

```
public class PaymentFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Payment> {

    @Override
    public Payment mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

        final Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.setDate(fieldSet.readDate("date"));
        payment.setSourceAccountNo(fieldSet.readString("source"));
        payment.setDestinationAccountNo(fieldSet.readString("destination"));
        payment.setAmount(fieldSet.readBigDecimal("amount"));
        return payment;
    }
```

my question is how can read data from two files and write it on db simultaneously?
for example my two files data are shown below:

one.csv

> date            source    destination      amount
>    02-10-2016       chennai       pune             1000
>   02-10-2016        bangalore       hyd           2000

two.csv

> source  date            amount    destination
>               chennai      02-10-2016      1000      pune
>              bangalore      02-10-2016     2000     hyd

Comment: Base on filename could we know what its format. If yes, we easily can build a partitioner and then go to Reader for processing. But we need to flag to determine which reader should be used for which file.

Comment: have a look at PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper. Unfortunately, this Mapper is NOT regex-based, therefore, you need to register the mapper for the format first example file for every digit ('0*', '1*',...'9*') and then to register a '*' for the mapper of the second format. You can also write your own matcher and use the PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper as a starting point. It is not that complicated